Doubt about the resolution of this linear system
I was following a video for solving linear systems and I tried to do an exercise:
\begin{cases}
3x + 3y + 2z = 3 \\
9x + 5y + 8z = 7 \\
3x + y + 3z = 2
\end{cases}So I wrote $A$: the coefficient matrix and with $A'$ I calculated the rank of the matrix. I wrote $C$: the augmented matrix and with $C'$ I calculated the rank of the matrix. So:$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 3 & 2 \\
9 & 5 & 8 \\
3 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
A' = \begin{pmatrix}
9 & 9 & 6 \\
0 & 4 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}C = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 3 & 2 & 3 \\
9 & 5 & 8 & 7 \\
3 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
\end{pmatrix}C' = \begin{pmatrix}
9 & 9 & 6 & 9 \\
0 & 4 & -2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} r(A) = r(C) = 2$$ The Rouché-Capelli theorem states that there exist solutions for the system if and only if the rank of the augmented matrix is equal to the rank of the coefficient matrix.

$det \ A = 0$ (determinant of the matrix)
$m =$ number of variables $(x,y,z)= 3$
$m > r = 3 > 2$ the system is possible but indeterminate, there is therefore $1$ free variable ($3-2 = 1$)
common rank = ($2$) therefore means that out of $3$ equations, $1$ is dependent, so only $2$ of these equations are independent, so I can only write $2$ of them

then using the matrix $C'$ (the one I used to calculate the rank):\begin{cases}
9x + 9y + 6z = 9 \\
4y - 2z = 2 \\
\end{cases}I choose to use $x$ as a free variable therefore:\begin{cases}
x = x \\
y = -\frac{2}{3} + 1 \\
z = \frac{1}{3}
\end{cases} My doubt comes when I solve the system by writing $x = x$. I saw a video that did something like this, but I think I was wrong. If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

When I did Gaussian Elimination, I got $$y = 1/2 + 1/2 z \ x = 1/2 - 7/6 z$$ You typically choose a temp variable name - but you have a free variable $z$.

@Moo but so I made a mistake in choosing my free variable? How did I know it was z?

See https://www.emathhelp.net/en/calculators/linear-algebra/gauss-jordan-elimination-calculator/?i=%5B%5B3%2C3%2C2%2C3%5D%2C%5B9%2C5%2C8%2C7%5D%2C%5B3%2C1%2C3%2C2%5D%5D&reduced=on

Moreover, what allowed you to write $y = -\frac23+ 1 ,
z = \frac13$? As for the "choice" of the free variable $z$, look at any proof of Rouché-Capelli theorem.

@AnneBauval I was following this video, although perhaps you won't understand what it says because it's in Italian, you can go to minute 39:36 and pause, you see that it uses y,t as free variables, but I don't understand why. It doesn't make any reference to the Gaussian elimination, or maybe I didn't understand correctly. This is the youtube video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC_E1now-2E

Thanks for that lovely experience of maths in Italian (which I never learnt but seem to understand). The crucial point is minute 33:27-28, where the ragazzo chooses the two free variables.

@AnneBauval yes but he says: "I decide to choose these 2 free variables", but he doesn't explain why, so I thought that in my case I could decide which one to choose and so I chose x.

As you got into row echelon form $C'$, the pivot positions are on columns $1,2$ (corresponding to $x,y$), and choosing the remaining $z$ as free variable would be more straightforward. Not saying you can't choose $x$ as free, and certainly you may interpret $C'$ as
$$\begin{align*}
9y+6z &= 9-9x\
4y-2z &= 2
\end{align*}$$
which is a system of linear equations in $y,z$.

@peterwhy but I should find the solution that Moo wrote in the comment above, if I choose free variables x,y I can't find this solution.

There should be just 1 free variable, not "free variables x,y".

@peterwhy ah yes I meant if I had chosen either x or y, not both, I actually wasn't very clear

If I continue with the equations
$$\begin{align*}
9y+6z &= 9-9x\
4y-2z &= 2
\end{align*}$$
and solve for $y,z$ in terms of $x$, then I get
$$\begin{align*}
y &= \frac57-\frac37x\
z &= \frac37 - \frac67x
\end{align*}$$

@peterwhy yes, I mean in solving a linear system, shouldn't there be a single solution? Because if I assume a free variable other than "z" in this case "x", we get a different solution. What I mean is whether or not this procedure is valid for solving a linear system?

You can substitute my $(x,y,z)$s in terms of $x$ or those from Moo in terms of $z$ back to your equations. Both should satisfy (if I haven't made calculation mistakes).

@peterwhy yes, I was unsure about this procedure because I saw that the solution of this linear system was like Moo's. This is why I asked you if choosing a free variable other than "z" was right, even if it led me to another result.
